# Reading in Many Variables in R

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to concatenate many vectors in R using `c()`. I have declared each of them to end with "_n" (i.e. `filename_n`). Now I want to know whether there is an easier method to read them all than just entering in each variable. I know in Bash I can use `ls *.file_extension > filename` to read all files in. Is there a similar method in R.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "datasets"? Does "abc_n" refer to the name of a variable in R and if so, what type is it (data frame? list? matrix?) Or does "abc_n" refer to a file on disk and if so, what format is it and how do you intend to read it into R (e.g. CSV -> data frame)?

Comment: I mean vectors which I already declared.

Comment: It is helpful/encouraged for you to edit your question to clarify it, for the benefit of future readers, on the basis of the discussion in the comments below ...

Comment: @GTyler: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and this http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand you might benefit from reading `?list.files`, `?read.table`, `?do.call`, `?sapply`. As a means of example,

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.txt", path = ".")
all = lapply(files, read.table, sep=",")
combined = do.call(c, all)
```

(untested)

EDIT: it looks like you're after `?ls` and `?get` now,

```
vars = lapply(ls(pattern = "_n"), get)
do.call(c, vars)
```

or, more succinctly,

```
sapply(ls(pattern = "_n"), get)
```

Comment: Indeed; my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311372/r-merging-data-from-many-files-and-plot-them/7311591#7311591) to a similar question earlier today might also be helpful.

Comment: My datasets are already declared in R. Should I take out the path from list.files()?

Comment: I tried files<-list.files(pattern="*_n",path=".") but it's giving me character(0).

Comment: @GTyler - Your question is a bit misleading; at the end you seem to imply you're asking about how to load multiple data sets into R and then combine them. But your other comments suggest that you've already loaded them and just need to combine them. I think you should edit your question to clarify.

Comment: +1 for list files. @GTyler: Your comparison with ls is misleading, because you state that your data is already "declared" in R. At least I am confused.

Comment: @ran2 I think he's trying to collect objects from workspace and concatenate them into one single variable. Baptiste showed how to get it done in his edited, second chunk using `do.call`.