# Loop through files in a directory and create variables with file names

Tags: r

I have a couple txt files in a directory

> dayton1.txt
>    datton2.txt
>    ...
>    dakton50.txt

and I want to create variables with the file names as names and read the corresponding files. How can I do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Do it like this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565095/602276

Comment: Thanks. I think it will do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `list.files()`, see it's help page at `?list.files`. E.g.:

```
R> getwd()
 [1] "/blah/blah/packages/analogue/analogue/pkg"
R> list.files()
 [1] "data"         "DESCRIPTION"  "DESCRIPTION~" "inst"         "man"         
 [6] "NAMESPACE"    "NAMESPACE~"   "R"            "src"          "tests"       
[11] "vignettes"
R> list.files("./inst")
[1] "ChangeLog"  "ChangeLog~" "CITATION"   "CITATION~"  "COPYING"   
[6] "doc"        "THANKS"     "TODO"
```