# How to use result from function as variable name in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to use file names as variable names in R.

Basically, I have a folder containing a list of files
and I want to load all files into R and use their names for variable names

```
for(i in list.files()) {
  loaddata(i,i)
}
```

This does not work, I also tried `as.name` and `paste`, both don't work. 
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your approach may spell trouble. I would suggest to work in a list. You can try this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function

Comment: i am still thinking in java way i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one liner that'll get you most of the way:

```
sapply(list.files("~/r"), FUN = function(X) assign(X, rnorm(1)))
```

This assigns a random number to an object in the global environment, with each object taking its name from the files in my `~/r/` directory.

To give a concrete example, say we had a directory `~/r` and we wished to read the files in and have them as seperate items in the environment -- then one would do the following:

```
list2env(sapply(list.files("~/r"), FUN = function(X) read.csv(X)), globalenv())
```

This is a combination of two commands that has the advantage of **not** cluttering the global environment with the list containing all the files.

In steps we would do:

```
inList <- sapply(list.files("~/r"), FUN = function(X) read.csv(X))
list2env(inList, globalenv())
```

Comment: i tried this, it does not load any variable only display file names along with random numbers, any modification?

Comment: i mean the command only gives result on console, but nothing is loaded into R

Comment: @user2324644 i edited the answer to give you a full example. note that i've restricted the case to `.csv` files, but it should be obvious with a moments effort how to generalise it to whatever case you have.