# open many dataframe and use logical order to find the answer in one time

Tags: r

I have many dataframe to open and assume it in folder named 'CNV'

Ss I read this link [1]: [Opening all files in a folder, and applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function)   but I'm still confuse.

Assume I have file name  a, b ,c ,d ,e .... z  in folder **CNV** in desktop

In these file have same column

```
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length
qd1234,  2666,  2888,  CN gain,  23,  235    
cc234,   1000,   1500,  CN loss,  5,  500
```

My question is how to  open all files in one time and after open all of these file

I want to select CN gain which have probe number more than 5, CN loss probe number more than 3,  and the probe/length less than 30

The expected result :

```
a
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe
qd1234,  2666,  2888,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9 
qd1534,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10
b
Sample, start, stop, event, probe, length, length/probe
qd234,  2666,  2888,  CN gain,  23,  235, 9 
qd534,  1200,  1800,  CN loss,  60,  600  10
```

Comment: Please do not use html `<br>`. And do learn to use the SO formatting conventions.

Comment: Where exactly are you having trouble? Opening the files or subsetting the dataframes?

Comment: I want to open the all file in one time and after open these file, I want to select data with the condition above. sorry about use <br>

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this.
When I create `crit` I look at the columns of the just imported `data.frame` and see which rows satisfy the specified criterion. Based on that, I subset the full `data.frame` and return (function returns the last line) the subset.

```
my.files <- list.files()

my.df <- sapply(my.files, function(x) {
  read.in <- read.table(x, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  crit <- with(read.in, which(probe > 5 & probe > 3 & (probe/length) < 30))
  read.in[crit, ]
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

Since we don't have a reproducible example, I'm demonstrating below how this subsetting actually works.

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = runif(10), z = rnorm(10))
xy # we expect row 6 to satisfy all the conditions
xy[with(xy, which(x > 5 & y < 0.5 & z < 0)), ]
```