# Opening and reading multiple netcdf files with RnetCDF

Tags: r, netcdf

Using R, I am trying to open all the netcdf files I have in a single folder (e.g 20 files)  read a single variable, and create a single data.frame combining the values from all files. I have been using RnetCDF to read netcdf files. For a single file, I read the variable with the following commands:

```
library('RNetCDF')
nc = open.nc('file.nc')
lw = var.get.nc(nc,'LWdown',start=c(414,315,1),count=c(1,1,240))
```

where 414 & 315 are the longitude and latitude of the value I would like to extract and 240 is the number of timesteps.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function) thread which explains how to open multiple files. Following it, I have managed to open the files using:

```
 filenames= list.files('/MY_FOLDER/',pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)
 ldf = lapply(filenames,open.nc)
```

but now I'm stuck. I tried

```
  var1= lapply(ldf, var.get.nc(ldf,'LWdown',start=c(414,315,1),count=c(1,1,240)))
```

but it doesn't work. 
The added complication is that every nc file has a different number of timestep. So I have 2 questions:

1: How can I open all files, read the variable in each file and combine all values in a single data frame? 
2: How can I set the last dimension in `count` to vary for all files?

Comment: It would probably be better just to use a loop, it's easier to put in tests for i/o assumptions, and especially if you have different params for each file. It's easy, write the ith version that works with one file and then loop around that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following `@mdsummer`'s comment, I have tried a do loop instead and have managed to do everything I needed:

```
# Declare data frame
df=NULL

#Open all files
files= list.files('MY_FOLDER/',pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)

# Loop over files
for(i in seq_along(files)) {
nc = open.nc(files[i])

# Read the whole nc file and read the length of the varying dimension (here, the 3rd dimension, specifically time)
lw = var.get.nc(nc,'LWdown')
x=dim(lw)

# Vary the time dimension for each file as required
lw = var.get.nc(nc,'LWdown',start=c(414,315,1),count=c(1,1,x[3]))

# Add the values from each file to a single data.frame
rbind(df,data.frame(lw))->df
}
```

There may be a more elegant way but it works.

Comment: Consider closing each connection rather than overwriting it, with close.nc(nc) after var.get.nc.

Comment: Hi...If you may,in c(414,315,1), what is value '1'? how come latitude and longitude is 414, 315, what is their unit? and what does count(1,1,x[3]) or time step mean here. I am stuck at that part? Please let me know

Comment: I have discussed similar problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521763/stacking-and-extracting-a-single-variable-from-multiple-netcdf-files

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the additional function parameters wrong. You should use `...` for that. Here's a simple example of how to pass `na.rm` to `mean`.

```
x.var <- 1:10
x.var[5] <- NA
x.var <- list(x.var)
x.var[[2]] <- 1:10
lapply(x.var, FUN = mean)
lapply(x.var, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

*edit*

For your specific example, this would be something along the lines of

```
var1 <- lapply(ldf, FUN = var.get.nc, variable = 'LWdown', start = c(414, 315, 1), count = c(1, 1, 240))
```

though this is untested.

Comment: Could you make your example more applicable to my request pls? I can't say that your answer helps me right now.

Comment: @SnowFrog Only the first two arguments get passed to `lapply`, anything beyond `FUN` is passed to `var.get.nc`, because it's considered to be part of `...`.

Comment: Using your example above, printing `var1` to screen gives `list()`.

Comment: @SnowFrog it's hard to judge without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much easier to do with CDO as you can select the *varying* timestep easily using the date or time stamp, and pick out the desired nearest grid point.  This would be an example bash script:

```
# I don't know how your time axis is
# you may need to use a date with a time stamp too if your data is not e.g. daily
# see the CDO manual for how to define dates. 
date=20090101 
lat=10
lon=50

files=`ls MY_FOLDER/*.nc`
for file in $files ; do
  # select the nearest grid point and the date slice desired:
  # %??? strips the .nc from the file name
  cdo seldate,$date -remapnn,lon=$lon/lat=$lat $file ${file%???}_${lat}_${lon}_${date}.nc
done
Rscript here to read in the files
```

It is possible to merge all the new files with cdo, but you would need to be careful if the time stamp is the same.  You could try *cdo merge* or *cdo cat* - that way you can read in a single file to R, rather than having to loop and open each file separately.