# Assigning objects in a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

My question is very simple I searched it and thought that I found the solution but I get an error. Here's my problem:

I have some files like this:

```
Mor_ldnew1.txt
Mor_ldnew2.txt
Mor_ldnew3.txt
.
.
.
```

And I want to store each of this files in different objects to then merge them but I got an error with my loop:

```
    for (i in 1:3){

read.table(paste("Mor_ld_new",i,".txt", sep="")) -> mor[i]      
}
```

This is the error:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "        }"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of syntax is `mor([i])`? Also, use `lapply`. There are many answers on SO, which show how to import files from a directory using `lapply`, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565095/1412059).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the parentheses around the `[i]`.

A more idiomatic way to write it would to use `lapply`.

Comment: I tried it but still nothing.

Comment: Error in mor[i] <- read.table(paste("MorN_LD_new", i, ".txt", sep = "")) : 
  object 'mor' not found

Comment: You have to define `mor` first.  Make sure you preallocate the list first (`mor <- vector('list', length = n.files)`)

Comment: I used mor <- vector('list', length=10) and the run the loop. No error but there are no objects named mor1, mor2, ...

Comment: The data is all stored in `mor`.  You can access the ith one by `mor[[i]]`.

Comment: I will take a look, but isn't there a way to have mor1, mor2, mor3, mor4, mor5, in different objects so I can merge them later?

Comment: I am googling lapply for naming objects in google but no luck either.

Comment: You can apply merge on a list assuming they have a common key using `lapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the loop:

```
for (i in 1:3){
assign(paste0("mor", i), read.table(paste("Mor_ld_new",i,".txt", sep="")))
}
```