# How to run same code on multiple files, or all files in directory

Tags: arrays, r, loops, for-loop, sox

so I am very new to coding and recently wrote a little program that involved R and sox. It looked like this

```
file <- "test.mp3"

testSox = paste("sox ",file," -n spectrogram -o ",file,".png stats",sep='')
sox = system(testSox, intern = TRUE)
print(sox)
```

Now, instead of assigning the one file manually within the code, I would just like to have this code read through all the mp3s in a folder automatically. Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Actually, I should add that I tried list.files, but when it comes to running the system() command, I get

"Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr) : 
  character string expected as first argument"

Here's the list.files code I tried:

```
> temp = list.files(path = ".", pattern=".mp3")
> 
> file <- temp
> 
> firstSox = paste("sox ",file," -n spectrogram -o ",file,".png stats",sep='')
> sox = system(firstSox, intern = TRUE)
Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr) : 
  character string expected as first argument
> print(sox)
```

I'm guessing this is not the correct route to go? Because I basically need to replace 'file' in the firstSox line with each mp3 that's in the temp array.  So instead of running:

```
file <- "test.mp3"
```

**...I would just like to have it re-assign each time for every file in the folder...**, so it runs through as test.mp3, then 1.mp3, then 2.mp3, then 3.mp, etc.

I've scoured the net, and just feel like I've hit a brick wall. As stated in the comments, I've read up on loops, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around how to incorporate it into what I have written. I feel like I just need someone to show me at least the way, or maybe even write me an example so I can wrap my head around it. Would greatly appreciate help and any tips on what I'm doing wrong and could correct. Thanks.

Comment: This could be interesting for you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function

Comment: Thanks, beginneR, I will check this page out ASAP.

Comment: Have you ever encountered the programming concept of a "loop"? Because that might be useful here.

Comment: Yes, but I have not incorporated it into any code of my own as of yet. Like I said, I'm brand new :-). I've read up on loops but I feel like an idiot because I don't know how to incorporate it into my code. This is actually just a portion of the code I wrote, and it all works for one file. I just need to wrap my head around how to get it to work with an entire folder of files except one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. I am using dir() instead of list.files, just because I find it easier. Remember there are many ways to do the same thing in R.

```
files <- dir(path = ".",pattern = ".mp3") #Get all the mp3 files

for(f in files) {     #Loop over the mp3 files one at a time

    firstSox = paste("sox ",f," -n spectrogram -o ",f,".png stats",sep='')
    sox = system(firstSox, intern = TRUE)
    print(sox)

}
```

Comment: Rohit, this worked beautifully! I added the rest of my code in, and it all works, except one thing. I have stop() notices in the original code because I didn't want certain mp3s going through the entire program. Is there another command other than stop() that could just make the loop stop if it comes to a certain if statement then restart the loop with the next mp3?

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure you must have figured it our by now, but look into `next` http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Looping. I was tempted to provide an answer using one of the apply functions but considering that you are just getting started, a for loop is easier to visualize. But Definitely look into  the solution provided by Greg Snow as that will allow you to write much more efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `firstSox` variable will be a vector of commands to run (`paste` will generate a vector, one string for each element of `file`).  So now you just need to run each command through `system`

One way to do this and capture the output is to use the `lapply` or `sapply` function:

```
sox <- lapply( firstSox, function(x) system(x, intern=TRUE) )
```

In this code `lapply` will run the function for each element of `firstSox` one at a time, the function just takes the current element (in `x`) and passes that to system.  Then `lapply` gathers all the outputs together and combines them into a list that it puts into `sox`.

If the results of each run give the same shape of results (single number or vector of same length) then you can use `sapply` instead and it will simplify the return into a vector or matrix.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, this works great for running the code up top, though I have a lot more code running on the file, so the for loop that Rohit supplied fits my overall situation more. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: @TwinSpiritRadio, you can write a function to do all the work you want, then pass that function to `sapply`.  In general if you only care about side effects then a `for` loop is fine, but when you want to store the output from each iteration then in the long run `lapply` and `sapply` will generally be better.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I'm going to apply it to my code in the way you just described and see what works best. Really appreciate the tips!