# Parallel computing in R: Run multiple files in same session [multi-threaded]

Tags: r, multithreading

Is there any way I can run a code on multiple files in the same R session?
Can I multi-thread in RStudio?

**EDIT:**
I have multiple files and I have to run an algorithm which takes around 2-5 hours depending on the file size and process time.
One way is to start multiple R sessions. But is there any way I can parallelise this process i.e run the algorithm on all whiles side-by-side while being in the same session?

Comment: You want to run same code on multiple files

Comment: If you want to run same code, R offers various options such as loop, apply family

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run same code on multiple files, or all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745964/how-to-run-same-code-on-multiple-files-or-all-files-in-directory)

Comment: Maybe the [Jobs](https://blog.rstudio.com/2019/03/14/rstudio-1-2-jobs/) functionality is what you looking for? Otherwise, have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) for an overview of parallel computing in R.

Comment: Without seeing your code this is hard to answer. ```parallel``` offers a start to parallelization, when setup correctly, but you likely also have to optimize your code as well. Lastly depending on the size of your files and the complexity of the function nothing except better hardware may help.

Comment: Knowing about `parallel` helps. I will explore parallelisation in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running code on different files and multi-threading are different things. With `lapply` I can run one function on several files / data frames but it will be done sequentially. Packages like `parallel` allow me to run process concurrently on multiple cores at the same time.

E.g.

```r
list_of_dfs <- c("a.csv","b.csv")

lapply(list_of_dfs, read.csv) #opens and reads all CSVs from the list sequentially
```

vs

```r
library(parallel)
list_of_dfs <- c("a.csv","b.csv")

mclapply(list_of_dfs, read.csv) #opens and reads all CSVs from the list at the same time
```

Note that in both cases the end result is the same, only the second case might be faster due to parallelization. So it depends on your use case for multi-threading.

Comment: mclapply belongs to which package?

Comment: ```parallel::mclapply``` is from the ```paralell``` package.

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘parallel’ is a base package, and should not be updated`

Comment: It is part of core R so you do not have to install it. You still have to load the library however.

Comment: `lapply(files, read.csv)` ==> elapsed time 0.007 and `mclapply(files, read.csv)` ==> elapsed time 0.019

Comment: What is your specific question? Yes simply running a process with ```mclapply``` is not faster depending on your setup of the parallel cores, the specific function and use case. If you need more specialized help improving speed of your code please add more info to your question.