# Read files with a specific a extension from a folder in R

Tags: r

I want to read files with extension .output with the function read.table.
I used pattern=".output" but its'not correct.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: please share the exact command you are using to load the data. The function `read.table` has no `pattern` argument.

Comment: is there something i can use to read files with a specific extension with read.table function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening all files in a folder, and applying a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/opening-all-files-in-a-folder-and-applying-a-function)

Comment: i still getting an empty list file so maybe the problem is on the address of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, heres how you could read in files with the extension ".output" and create a list of tables

```
 list.filenames <- list.files(pattern="\\.output$")
 trialsdata <- lapply(list.filenames,read.table,sep="\t")
```

or if you just want to read them one at a time manually just include the extention in the filename argument.

```
read.table("ACF.output",sep=...)
```

Comment: i have already set my work directory as setwd("./data"). The files i want are in the same folder but with the above commands i am getting an empty list.

Comment: when setting the WD you need the full file path setwd("C:\\Users\\username\\folder") or setwd("C:/Users/username/folder")

Comment: @tskir93 check your working directory is what you think it is using `getwd()`

Comment: just try list.files() and all files in the folder will be listed. If they don't then you have not properly set up your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

So finally because i didn't found a solution(something is going wrong with my path) i made a text file including all the .output files with  `ls *.output > data.txt`.
After that using :

```
files = read.table("./data.txt")
```

i am making a data.frame including all my files and using

```
files[] <- lapply(files, as.character)
```

Finally with `test = read.table(files[i,],header=F,row.names=1)`
we could read every file which is stored in i (i = no of line).