# How do I read multiple binary files in R?

Tags: r, binary

Suppose we have files in one folder file1.bin, file2.bin, ... , and file1460.bin in directory C:\R\Data and we want to read them and  make a loop to go from 1 to 4 and take the average then from 4 to 8 average  and so on till  1460.in the end will get 360 files
I tried to have them in a list,but  did not know how to make the loop.

How do I read multiple files  and manupulat them? in R language
I have been wasting countless hourse to figuer it out.any help

Comment: Here is a link that might be helpful, although the link does not seem to address *.bin files specifically.  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/code/read_multiple.htm

Comment: Perhaps a helpful starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420207/manipulating-multiple-files-in-r

Comment: See also your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128084/how-do-i-read-multiple-binary-files-in-in-different-folders-in-r

Answer (score 0):

```
results <- array(dim=360)
for (i in 1:360){
  results <- mean(yourlist[[(i*4):(i*4+3)]])
}
```

YMMV with the mean(yourList) call, but that structure would be how you could loop through the data once it's loaded.

Comment: Thanks alot.in fact here is my code  listfile<-dir("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Wind\\")
results <- array(0, dim=c(365,720,360))

for (i in 1:365){
  results <- mean(listfile[[(i*4):(i*4+3)]])
   writeBin(results)}

Comment: Sorry ignore the previous .Thanks alot.in fact here is my code                         listfile<-dir("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Wind\\")                   results <- array(0, dim=c(365,720,360))                           for (i in 1:365){ results <- mean(listfile[[(i*4):(i*4+3)]]) writeBin(results)} but I got this Error: in listfile[[(i * 4):(i * 4 + 3)]] :  attempt to select more than one element.               what I want to do is to read those 365 binary files and then take the averag for every four files and then write to binary so I will get finally 40 files.Any help

Comment: As @Mark suggested, you may be better off looking at a resource like: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/code/read_multiple.htm. It's not really clear what your specific problem is. If you can post a couple of the files online, maybe I could revise the answer.

The basic idea is that you'll load all of the files into a list, then loop through and take the mean of every 4 using something like the loop above.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.where can I upload the files so you can have alook on them or if you give me your email,i send them to.

Comment: is this  right???         Testarray<-array(0, dim=c(1460,720,360)) 
 listfile<-dir("C:\\PHD\\Climate Data\\Wind\\") 
 for (i in c(1:1460)) { 
     Testarray <- file(listfile[i], "rb") 
      Testarray[i,,]<- readBin(conne, integer(), size=2,  n=365*360*720, 
 signed=F) 
             results <- mean(listfile[[(i*4):(i*4+3)]]) 
             results1<-    writeBin(results) 
 close(conne) 
 }

Comment: Without access to your data, I really have no idea if that's right. Typically, people post it publicly online and share the URL in the question.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/home    here is one file out of 365 files in one folder that I want to work on