# how to merge one file with multiple files in a list to generate multiple merged files in R using loop function

Tags: merge

I have a list of 24 PAIR files.
I would like to merge each PAIR file with an NDF file, producing 24 merged pair-ndf files.
The aim is to write each merged file to extract information from the file to create XYS files.
However, here, I am trying to perform a loop function to merge the NDF file with each of the 24 PAIR files.

```
#read in files
allfilesList=lapply(list.files(), read.delim, header=TRUE, sep="\t", as.is=TRUE)

#read files in a list, and merge each file with ndf using loop function to merge, Attempt#1
for(file in allfileslist){
if(!exists("dataset")){
dataset=read.table(allfileslist, header=TRUE, sep="\t", as.is=TRUE)
}
for(file in allfileslist){
if(exists("dataset")){
temp_dataset=read.table(allfileslist, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
dataset=merge(file, ndf, by="PROBE_ID", temp_dataset)
rm(temp_dataset)
}
}
#read files in a list, and merge each file with ndf using loop function to merge, Attempt#2
for(i in 1:length(allfileslist)){
readnmerge=read.delim(file=paste(getwd(), allfileslist[i], sep="\t"), header=T)
dataMerge=merge(readnmerge, ndf, by="PROBE_ID")
}
```

However, both cases it seems to iterate over only one file and IMAGE_ID is the first column in each PAIR file.

I will keep working at it. Although, if anyone could suggest a better way, please reply.
Regards,
FRANKLIN

Comment: Should the for loops be `dataset = read.table(file, ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile, so I thought I help answer my own question.
Also, I found the pdInfoBuilder and Oligo packages in Bioconductor. 
There is a way to convert pair to xys files using R.
I found this post here:
[Manipulating multiple files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420207/manipulating-multiple-files-in-r)
which was very helpful.